# Solve the following integral using substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Why is $$\int_a^bf(ta + (1 - t)b) dt=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$$ ? I used a substitution $x = ta + (1-t)b$ but I get $1/(a - b)$ instead of $1/ (b - a)$.
Please help! Thank you.

Comment: The integration limits in the left integral should be $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the bounds of integration on the left go from $t=0$ to $1$. In that case, you are correct. Remember that the bounds of integration change when you  change variables. Note that $t=0$ corresponds to $x=b,$ and $t=1$ corresponds to $x=a.$ So,
$$\int_0^1f(ta + (1 - t)b) dt=\frac{1}{a-b}\int_b^a f(x)dx=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx.$$